# Django - SlugRelated to return full object

Tags: python, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I work in DRF, and have a **serializer** which looks like this:

```
class PendingRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    driver = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username',
        queryset=User.objects.all()
    )

    passenger = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username',
        queryset=User.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PendingRequest
        fields = ('passenger', 'driver', 'ride', )
        read_only_fields = ('passenger', )
```

**The model:**

```
class PendingRequest(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='driver_pending_requests')
    passenger = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='passenger_pending_requests')
    ride = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
```

I can successfully return the **username** of the **driver** and **passenger** with the **SlugRelatedField**.

Now - for the **ride** field, I want to get the **whole Ride object**, not only the one field (like in the passenger and driver).

How can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested serialization.

DRF offers a feature called [nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects).

For your example you could do the following:

```
class PendingRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    driver = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username',
        queryset=User.objects.all()
    )

    passenger = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username',
        queryset=User.objects.all()
    )

    ride = RideSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = PendingRequest
        fields = ('passenger', 'driver', 'ride', )
        read_only_fields = ('passenger', )
```

This will produce the normal JSON and instead of showing the PK of the ride instance in the ride field, it will nest the entire ride object.
You will of course need to write that `RideSerializer` for that to work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem with this is that when I create a PendingRequest (POST) I put in the ride field the PK. I want to keep doing that (POST with pk) and when I send Get - to get the whole field. is thhis possible?

Comment: @OfekAgmon Well, there are a few options, all which I think are not as smooth as I'd want.

One is to use different views for POST and GET and use different serializers, one with nested ride and one without.

The other which is dirtier is to decide inside your view which serializer to invoke... also that depends on whether you are using a generic view or the base APIView.

Comment: @OfekAgmon Another option is to keep ride as it is (PK) and add an additional field, a SerializerMethodField  that will return the ride object under a different field name.

Comment: thanks for your answers guys. I ended up using two serizlizers - one for POST and one for GET. thanks for your advice:)